# Improper double integral evaluation by changing the order of integration

Tags: multivariable-calculus, improper-integrals

I was watching an MIT OCW recitation video about exchanging the order of integration on double integrals.

The example was:
$$\intop_{t=0}^{\frac{1}{4}}\intop_{u=\sqrt{t}}^{\frac{1}{2}}\frac{e^{u}}{u}\:\mathrm{d}u\:\mathrm{d}t$$, which easily solves to $1-\frac{\sqrt{e}}{2}$.

But something is bugging me. $\frac{e^u}{u}$ is not defined for $u=0$ and hence this is an improper integral, right?

So the question is: how do we know that this integral converges?

Comment: Are you using the Lebesgue integral? If so, then Tonelli says that you can swap the order regardless (since the underlying space is $\sigma$-finite and the integrand is non-negative).

Comment: Unfortunately,no. In fact, I got no idea what a Lebesgue integral is, lol!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an answer at present as I need to find an appropriate definition of the improper Riemann integral on a rectangle. I have written that a certain function below is integrable as an improper Riemann integral, but this is based on some presumption of 'reasonableness' until I find the appropriate definition.

The interchange is straightforward to justify using the Lebesgue integral, so the result it true, however presumably the desire is to establish the result using the Riemann integral.

Let $f(t,u) = 1_{[\sqrt{t},{1 \over 2}]} (u) { e^u \over u}$, for $(t,u) \in R=[0,{1 \over 4}] \times (0, { 1 \over 2}]$.

Since $f(t,\sqrt{t}) = { e^{\sqrt{t}} \over \sqrt{t}}$, we see that $f$ is unbounded on $R$, hence the integral must be improper (as a Riemann integrable function must be bounded).

Note that $u \mapsto { e^u \over u}$ is decreasing on $(0,{ 1 \over 2}]$, hence
$f(t,u) \le { e^{\sqrt{t}} \over \sqrt{t}} \le {1 \over \sqrt{t}}$, for $(t,u) \in R$.

The function $(t,u) \mapsto {1 \over \sqrt{t}}$ is integrable as an improper Riemann integral.

Comment: I cannot (quickly) find a satisfactory reference for the improper integral. Some approachs (inspired by Marsden's "Real analysis") is to let $f_M(x) = \min(f(x),M)$ and define $\int f = \lim_{M \to \infty} f_M$ (assuming the limit exists). Another would be to 'approximate' $R$ by smaller rectangles that 'converge' in some sense, so that $f$ is Riemann integrable on the smaller rectangles.

Comment: In fact what is really confusing me is that I learned to compute improper integrals by doing something like $$\intop_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{x}dx = \lim_{T\to0}\intop_{T}^{1}\frac{1}{x}dx$$. So the integral will converge if the limit exists. But I didn't see nothing like that approach in the video, not even a consideration to the fact that it was an improper integral.

Comment: It is good that you pay attention to the detail, many people are sloppy with such things.